# The Itō Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In stochastic calculus and specifically for mathematical finance Ito's lemma is used for time varying processes

I need to know intuitively why the Ito Integral is stochastic?

Answer (score 1):

To put it in simple terms:

The integral requires a measure (i.e., $dx$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and the measure here is a Wiener measure - a measure w.r.t. a stochastic process.

If you approach it from the direction of defining the integral as a limit of sums then in each sum you have a random number (normally distributed and all that) multiplying the integrand.

I think a good reference to look at would be Kloeden & Platen "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations". I found Lefebvre's "Applied Stochastic Processes" helpful too.